# How can I pass an Int from one activity to another?

Tags: android, variables, global-variables

I'm creating a Highscore, so I have to pass a Int to other acitivity to increment it when a person answer correctly a question. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass int , string or whatever you want using **Intent**.

```
String SCORE_TAG = "score";
int highScore = 120;

    Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, YourActivity.class);        
    i.putExtra(SCORE_TAG,highScore);
    startActivity(i);
```

And in YourActivity use this.

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
 my_score = i.getIntExtra(SCORE_TAG,0); // 0  for default value.
```